# Add tuning stage to DVC pipeline

Tags: hyperparameter-tuning, pipelines

I have an ML pipeline built with DVC that I use for experiment tracking. This allows running and tracking several experiments. Also, using hydra integration I can grid search hyper parameters. However, I would like to tune hyper parameters using more sophisticated algorithms (e.g., bayesian optimisation) through Keras Tuner for example.

I am aware that I can just write a script using Keras Tuner. However, I would like to avoid duplicating the code and also integrate the tuning into the pipeline so that tuning is dependent on stages like data import and preprocessing.

My question is what is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm from the DVC team. This is a great question. Do you want to save each trial in your search as its own experiment? It could be overkill and might make sense to start with saving the entire search as an experiment, along with some metrics about each trial (for example, you could make a plot of the metrics for each trial) or a summary of the search. You could still save the best model or several models if you aren't sure which one to ultimately keep.